# How do i create a Shortcut Commands in the Terminal that works globally and within a workspace

Tags: php, command-line-interface

i need to create an alias that would provide a shortcuts to `php app (arguments...)` for php developers using an open source project i am working on. Like create a new app globally with a command like this one below;

**To create a new app**

```
app init socialApp
```

**or to do a database migration within socialApp project**

```
app migrate --silent
```

where **app** is an alias or sort.

My research lead me to this article https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-shortcut-commands-in-the-terminal-for-your-mac-9e016e25e4d7 but really tied to MacOs users and can't figure out how i could serve for a new project or perform an action if command is ran on a workspace.

Would appreciate an head start.

Comment: Can you start a bounty for this question ?

Comment: Yea i think i would

Answer (score 0):

it took a while but I finally got a solution. Since my framework would be publicly available for download and usage. I decided to come back to this question and find a workaround.

Here are the steps I took. *(Using PHP on a MAC OS)*

1. Create a folder that would house an executable file. Mine was called (**moorexa**) with no extension.
2. Add the path to your ~/.bash_profile *( For demonstration, my folder would be created in the Applications directory )*.
3. Open up your terminal and run `nano ~/.bash_profile`
4. Add the path. Mine is `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/moorexa`. Now, moorexa is the name of the folder, the only file I have in it is also called moorexa. So i can just call `moorexa start` or `moorexa compile` from the terminal.
5. Close the file with `CMD + X` and enter `Y` to save.
6. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` to update the session of your current terminal.

We are almost through with this solution. The final thing is getting to know if you are running this command from a project identified by you. For me, I wanted to push responsibility to the assist manager that comes with the default installation of moorexa, if I am executing the request within a moorexa project.

Well, looking at the architecture, the framework has an init file, so this is what you could do also.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// get the working directory
define('WORKING_DIRECTORY', $_SERVER['PWD'] . '/');

// get the arguments
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];

// check for init within current directory
$initFile = WORKING_DIRECTORY . 'init.php';

// message to screen
function screen_display($message, string $type = '')
{
    // reset color
    $reset = "\033[0m";

    // get type
    $color = $type == 'error' ? "\033[31m" : ($type == 'success' ? "\033[32m" : '');

    // print message
    fwrite(STDOUT,  $color . $message . $reset . "\n");
}


// check if init file exists
if (file_exists($initFile)) :

    // change working directory
    chdir(WORKING_DIRECTORY);

    // require the assist file
    return (file_exists('assist') ? include_once 'assist' : null);
    
endif;

// command string 
$commands = "
Try any of this commands:\n
(1.) moorexa create 
(2.) moorexa update 
(3.) moorexa create <project-name>
(4.) moorexa create <project-name> -service
(5.) moorexa create <project-name> -frontend
(6.) moorexa prepare

For more information, please visit www.moorexa.com";


// not within a working project
if (count($argv) == 1 || (isset($argv[1]) && strlen(trim($argv[1])) == 0)) return screen_display("
Not within a working moorexa directory\n
{$commands}
");


// manage request
switch(strtolower($argv[1])) :

    // create command
    case 'create':

        // get the folder name
        $folderName = isset($argv[2]) ? $argv[2] : '';

        // check for '-'
        if (strpos($folderName, '-') !== false) :

            // push to next argv
            $argv[3] = $folderName;

            // replace name
            $folderName = '';

        endif;

        // get directory
        $directory = rtrim(WORKING_DIRECTORY . $folderName, '/') . '/';

        // stop if directory exists
        if ($folderName != '' && is_dir($directory)) return screen_display('Workspace exists. Failed to overwrite', 'error');

        // create folder if it doesn't exists
        if (!is_dir($directory)) mkdir($directory);

        // get the create type
        $createType = isset($argv[3]) ? strtolower($argv[3]) : 'frontend';

        // remove dash
        $createType = ltrim($createType, '-');

        // open storage
        $storage = __DIR__ . '/storage/' . ($createType == 'service' ? 'backend' : $createType) . '.zip';

        // does file exists
        if (!file_exists($storage)) return implode("\n", [
            screen_display('Invalid create type "'.$createType.'"', 'error'),
            screen_display($commands)
        ]);

        // file exists
        // open zip manager
        screen_display('Creating a blank project for "'.$createType.'"', 'success');

        // get size
        $fileSize = filesize($storage);

        // print size to screen
        screen_display('Pouring size ' . round($fileSize / 1024) . 'kb into '.$directory.'');

        // load zip archive
        $zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

        // open file
        if (!$zipArchive->open($storage)) return screen_display('Could not start extracting. It\'s possible that the .zip file has been corrupted or we dont have full permission to continue. Please run moorexa update or contact support.', 'error');

        // starting extraction
        screen_display('Starting extraction from cache', 'success');

        // sleep
        sleep(2);

        // start now
        if ($zipArchive->extractTo($directory)) $zipArchive->close();

        // all good
        screen_display('Your project has been created successfully.', 'success');

        // change directory
        $changeDirectory = $directory == WORKING_DIRECTORY ? 'run ' : 'cd into "'.$directory.'", and run ';

        // final note
        screen_display("\n".'So what next?'."\n". $changeDirectory .' "moorexa install" to load required dependencies, or "moorexa serve" to start development server if dependencies already exists.'."\n\n".'Thank you for building with Moorexa..');

    break;

    // prepare
    case 'prepare':

        // check for folder installation
        if (!is_dir(__DIR__ . '/storage')) mkdir(__DIR__ . '/storage');
        
        // try to download from svn.

    break;

    // invalid command 
    default:
        screen_display('Invalid command "'.$argv[1].'"', 'error');
        screen_display($commands);
endswitch;
```

And this worked. Still implementing more features, I hope to create an installer that would register the path and complete this process on multiple platforms.